# best way to store data from mysql result using C

Tags: mysql, struct

My C programming is decidedly rusty:-(

I have studied http://zetcode.com/db/mysqlc/ and essentially comfortable with it.

But I am unsure of the best way of storing the data retrieved.

```
  int num_fields = mysql_num_fields(result);
  MYSQL_ROW row;
  while ((row = mysql_fetch_row(result))) {
  for(int i = 0; i < num_fields; ) {
    printf("%s ", row[i] ? row[i] : "NULL"); 
  } 
  printf("\n");
```

this works fine and give me exactly the correct results.

Being familiar with perl hashes, I am tempted to use a C structure.  Each record in my (small) database consists of different types of columns: char, float, int etc.

So I have:

```
    struct Parameter {
      char  name[LEN_NAME];
      float max;
      float min;
      float sample_interval;
      int active;
      char units[LEN_UNITS];
      char start[LEN_START];
      char start_time[LEN_START_TIME];
      char end[LEN_END];
      char end_time[LEN_END_TIME];
      char type[LEN_TYPE];
    };  
    struct Parameter parameters[MAX_PARAMETERS];
```

Where the LENs are defined constants.

I am trying things like:

```
    num_fields = mysql_num_fields(result);
    int r = 0;
    while ((row = mysql_fetch_row(result))) {
    for(int i = 0; i < num_fields; i++) {
      printf("%s ", row[i] ? row[i] : "NULL");
      sscanf(row[0], "%LEN_NAMEs",  parameters[r].name);
      sscanf(row[1], "%d",      &parameters[r].max);
```

Which seems to be working OK for the chars, but not for the other types.

Struggling.  Perhaps I am up a gum tree!

Comment: Your `parameters[r].max` is a float. Use `%f` as a format there. `%d` is for integers, like `parameters[r].active`. Does it work there?

Comment: Ah bullseye.   Well spotted, thank you so much.

Comment: I am now using: sprintf(parameter[r].blah, "%s", row[somenumber], but I'm finding that on one occassion a field is being augmented by its immediately following neighbour:-(   Any ideas how to track this down.   Thanks.

Comment: fixed!  All I did was add int j;j=sprintf(.......).   Should I be worried!?

Comment: `%s` expects a nul-terminated string in `row[x]`. Probably `row[x]` isn't? I'm not familiar with `mysql_fetch_row()` in C. I remember a case when the `\0` was appended only when the string was shorter than the max. column length. E.g. your column is char(3) then `'a'` would give `'a\0'`, `'ab'` would give `'ab\0'` but `'abc'` would only give `'abc'` (without the `\0`. But that's very old knowledge and I really cannot remember when and where this happened.

Comment: Yes, I would be worried because the `int j=sprintf(…);` cannot have any impact on how `sprintf` behaves. Except it occupies 4 bytes in memory which could be an indication that your construction writes into memory where it shouldn't.